# Handling exception when a folder already exists with a client name

Tags: python

I'm creating folders from each name save in the "Clients.txt' file. I want to add the new name entered in the text file, but the file exists error I think is preventing it.

```
import os
with open('Clients.txt',) as x:
for line in x:
line = line.strip()
os.mkdir(str(line))



here is for another folder. I want to work the same way too.
import os

folderdir = r"D:\Administration\New Customers"
with open("Clients.txt",) as newfolder:
    for line in newfolder:
        line = line.strip()
        foldername = line.strip()
        folderpath = os.path.join(folderdir, foldername)
        os.mkdir(folderpath)
print("Folder Created")
fle = open("Clients.txt", "r+")
fle.truncate(0)
fle.close
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a directory only if it don't exist, then you could can one of two things.  You can either check first to see if the directory already exists, and only create it if it doesn't:

```
with open('Clients.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        line = line.strip()
        if not os.path.exists(line):
            # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
            os.mkdir(line)
```

or, you can just try to create the directory, and then ignore any exception you get by catching it and not doing anything with it.

```
with open('Clients.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        line = line.strip()
        try:
            os.mkdir(line)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: The first script worked. thanks!

Comment: @MsDi - Cool.  How about hitting the up arrow and green checks on my answer?